# Подсветка строк с одинаковыми данными в WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

На форме есть таблица с данными, выбиратель цвета, кнопка.

1. Выбираю нужную строку
2. Выбираю цвет
3. Нажимаю кнопку "Подсветить"
4. Выделяются все строки, которые содержат аналогичную информацию (но строки не 100% идентичны)
5. Выбираю другую строку
6. Выбираю другой цвет...

Не могу придумать как это сделать. Есть идеи?

Кажется, что копать нужно сюда:

```
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="{x:Static loc:Resources.StateOld}">
      <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
          <Binding Path="SensorName" Converter="{StaticResource RowBackgroundConverter}"/>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </DataTrigger>
```

Но не совсем понятно, как привязаться к нескольким свойствам (колонкам). Нужно сравнивать как минимум по трем свойствам.

Самый простой путь, который придумал - это добавить свойство Color объектам, которые выводятся в таблицу. По кнопке менять им это свойство. Но хочется без этого.

Comment: Делать это во viewmodel, а не в xaml разметке ?

Comment: только у меня не использован mvvm изначально =( Вот, говорю, добавить свойство к объектам.

Comment: так никогда не поздно начать юзать mvvm

Comment: Буду пробовать mvvm, но получается, что свойство  Colour все равно должно быть? Во viewmodel его менять?

Comment: это уже вам решать. Вы можете либо Color свойство добавить, либо что то типа GroupId и в XAML уже конвертить группу в цвет конвертером

Comment: Что такое groupId?

Comment: ну вы либо красите строки в один цвет во viewmodel, либо как то определяете эти строки в одну группу и конвертите группу в цвет конвертером. Орпделить строки в одну группу вы можете добавив признак группы (просто свойство типа int GroupId{get;set;) во вьюмодель строки

Comment: я применил mvvm, но я так и не понимаю, как я могу поменять цвет строки. DataTrigger не биндится к свойствам из ViewModel, он биндится к свойствам модели.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал пока так, введя новое свойство объекту - RowColor. Наверно очень не оптимально с циклом. Но делать нужно...(

```
if (EventsDataGrid.SelectedItem is Event selectedEvent)
{
    foreach (EventForReport item in viewSource.View)
    {
       bool equal = selectedEvent.DeviceName == item.DeviceName &&
                    selectedEvent.Ip == item.Ip &&
                    selectedEvent.SensorName == item.SensorName &&
                    selectedEvent.SensorValueText == item.SensorValueText;

        if (equal)
        {
            item.RowColor = Brushes.Yellow;
        }
    }
}               

viewSource.View.Refresh();
```